# When I assign int to float variable, then I print the variable. Why the output is 1 but not 1.0?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    float i = 1;
    std::cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

I read ***C++ Primer***, it said when we assign int to float variable, the fractional part is recorded as 0. Then I try the code above, I couldn't understand the output.

Comment: It's up to `std::cout` to print that `0` or not, not the `float` itself

Comment: If you assign `1.0f` to your float variable it will also point as `1`. The source of the value doesn't matter. As the answers say, it's the default for converting floating-point values to text.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's up to `std::cout` to print that `0` or not, not `i` itself. `std::cout` choose to not print that `0`, so all you can see is `1`.

You can change it using `<iomanip>`'s `std::setprecision()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    float i = 1;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << i;
    return 0;
}
```

This above prints:

```
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the output is 1 but not 1.0?

Because you didn't specify such formatting, and because that's not how floats are formatted by default. You can change the formatting using io manipulators.